# Mostrar rama feature como una única línea aunque tenga varios commits (basura)

Tags: git, git-flow

Uso git flow.
Imagina que creas una nueva feature que te lleva una semana hacerla. A lo largo de una semana vas haciendo varios commits:

- parte 1 hecha
- parte 2 hecha
- ....
- parte N hecha

Todos esos commits no aportan nada ya que los voy haciendo a medida que voy avanzado.

Después hago git flow feature finish featureNueva para finalizar la rama
Todos los "commits basura" que he ido metiendo se pasarán a la rama develop con lo que todo queda mucho menos legible.

Lo que quiero es todos los cambios realizados en esa rama feature se muestren en develop como una única línea.

¿Cómo se puede lograr esto? es decir que quedara de la siguiente forma:

- Feature 1
- Resto de modificaciones de la rama develop

En lugar de

- parte 1 hecha
- parte 2 hecha
- ....
- parte N hecha
- Resto de   modificaciones de rama develop

Comment: ¿Como una única línea o como un único commit?

Comment: En el historial de develop me gustaría que quedase:
Feature 1
Resto de modificaciones de la rama develop

En lugar de 

parte 1 hecha
parte 2 hecha
....
parte N hecha
Resto de modificaciones de rama develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar git rebase -i HEAD~n donde n es el número de commits que quieres juntar por ejemplo los 5 ultimos commits de tu rama

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Eso te mandará al editor por default para que "reescribas" la historia de esa rama.

Primero escoges el commit base, puede ser el primero y los demas sustituyes pick por s

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en el siguiente editor elijes el o los comentarios que queden para el commit (porque ahí van 5 comentarios), y en el editor solo los comentas con # o bien puedes dejar todos para mostrar los pasos realizados.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Te recomiendo hacer esto antes de mezclar tu rama a develop

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que buscaba. Me parece un mecanismo tremendamente retorcido (al tener que hacerlo desde el editor...) pero es cuestión de acostumbrarse supongo.
Muchas gracias Omar!!